# AWK/SED. How to remove parentheses in simple text file

Tags: sed, awk

I have a text file looking like this:

```
(-9.1744438E-02,7.6282293E-02) (-9.1744438E-02,7.6282293E-02)  ... and so on.
```

I would like to modify the file by removing all the parenthesis and a new line for each couple
so that it look like this:

```
-9.1744438E-02,7.6282293E-02
-9.1744438E-02,7.6282293E-02
...
```

A simple way to do that?

Any help is appreciated,

Fred

Comment: `sed 's/[)(]//g' file.txt` should do.

Comment: `grep -E -o '[0-9E,.-]+' file.txt` should do.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I would use `tr` for this job:

```
cat in_file | tr -d '()' > out_file
```

With the `-d` switch it just deletes any characters in the given set.

To add new lines you could pipe it through two `tr`s:

```
cat in_file | tr -d '(' | tr ')' '\n' > out_file
```

Comment: True.  Of the three tools, tr seems to have the smallest binary, and will probably yield the best performance.  +1.

Comment: Instead of two pipes you can do `tr " " "\n" < <(tr -d '()' < in_file)`

Comment: and just to note, this is the fairly rare useFUL use of `cat`: `tr` is purely a filter and only operates on stdin

Comment: @ghoti, just because it's a small program doesn't necessarily mean it will be the fastest, especially if you have to pipe a couple of them together. You'd have to benchmark a couple of different solutions.

Comment: @glenn This is still UUOC.  tr -d '()' < in_file

Comment: @glennjackman, tr uses simple things like getwchar() to find things and doesn't have to do complex stuff like regex parsing.  Both sed and awk are programming languages (to some extent).  It's only natural that they'd be (1) bigger binaries and (2) slower.  See http://pastebin.com/d4ft9L9E for benchmarks.

Answer (score 6):

As was said, almost:

```
sed 's/[()]//g' inputfile > outputfile
```

or in awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/[()]/,""); print;}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: Both are good solutions but they both print the data on the same line. OP needs a newline though that looks like was edited to add later on. :P

Comment: Yup, this answer was generated for a previous incarnation of the question.  Looks like there's an accepted answer already though; not with the effort to answer the question a second time.

Answer (score 2):

This would work -

```
awk -v FS="[()]" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i }' inputfile > outputfile
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
(-9.1744438E-02,7.6282293E-02) (-9.1744438E-02,7.6282293E-02)

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v FS="[()]" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i }' file
-9.1744438E-02,7.6282293E-02
-9.1744438E-02,7.6282293E-02
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
echo "(-9.1744438E-02,7.6282293E-02) (-9.1744438E-02,7.6282293E-02)" |
sed 's/) (/\n/;s/[()]//g'
-9.1744438E-02,7.6282293E-02
-9.1744438E-02,7.6282293E-02
```

Answer (score 2):

Guess we all know this, but just to emphasize:

Usage of bash commands is better in terms of time taken for execution, than using awk or sed to do the same job. For instance, try not to use sed/awk where grep can suffice.

In this particular case, I created a file 100000 lines long file, each containing characters "(" as well as ")". Then ran

```
$  /usr/bin/time -f%E -o log cat file | tr -d "()"
```

and again,

```
$  /usr/bin/time -f%E -ao log sed 's/[()]//g' file
```

And the results were:

05.44 sec : Using tr

05.57 sec : Using sed

Answer (score 1):

```
cat in_file | sed 's/[()]//g' > out_file
```

Due to formatting issues, it is not entirely clear from your question whether you also need to insert newlines.

Comment: Yes, new lines is also needed