# Load text file python could not convert string to float

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
(1064.2966,1898.787,1064.2986,1898.787,1064.2986,1898.785,1064.2966,1898.785)
(1061.0567,1920.3816,1065.1361,1920.2276,1065.5847,1915.9657,1065.4726,1915.2927,1061.0985,1914.3955,1058.1824,1913.9468,1055.6028,1913.9468,1051.0044,1916.19,1051.5651,1918.8817,1056.0514,1918.9939,1058.9675,1919.6668,1060.8741,1920.4519)
```

etc (all rows have different lengths)

when I use

`np.loadtxt(filename,dtype=float,delimiter=',')`

I get

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: (1031.4647
```

Comment: Looks like you need to strip off the parentheses.

Comment: I did that. Now I get ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2

Comment: Of course it does. The documentation for [loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) says `Each row in the text file must have the same number of values.`

Answer (score 5):

I think np.loadtxt expects numbers so it does not know how to convert a value which starts with a '(', I think you have two choices here:

```
lines = []
with open('datafile') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')[1:-1]  # this removes first and last parentheses from the line
        lines.append([float(v) for v in line.split(',')])
```

in this way you end up with `lines` which is a list of lists of values (i.e. `lines[0]` is a list of the values on line 1).

The other way to go is modifying the data file to remove the parentheses, which you can do in many ways depending on the platform you are working on.

In most Linux systems for instance you can just do something along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914435/awk-sed-how-to-remove-parentheses-in-simple-text-file)

EDIT: as suggested by @AlexanderHuszagh in the comments section, different systems can have different ways of representing newlines, so a more robust solution would be:

```
lines = []
with open('datafile') as infile:
    file_lines = infile.read().splitlines()
for line in file_lines:
    lines.append([float(v) for v in line[1:-1].split(',')])
```

Comment: It's better to use the function splitlines()[0][1:-1] rather than rstrip('\n'), in case the line has a carriage return delimiter ('\r\n').

If the file size isn't giant, then just splitlines() everything, and for each line, do your [1:-1] and then float conversion.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: right, I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because of the parentheses, you can replace it this way:

```py
s = open(filename).read().replace('(','').replace(')','')
```

This return a list of arrays:

```py
arrays = [np.array(map(float, line.split(","))) for line in s.split("\n")]
```